# const usage inside for loop, why this behaviour?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a for loop in my nodejs code

```
const saveDocument = co.wrap(function *(documentData, user, locale) {
    var now = moment();
    var creationDateLongString = now.format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss");
    var creationDateShortString = now.format("YYYYMMDD");

    var outputChildFolder = documentData.code + '_' + creationDateLongString + '_' + documentCounter;
    var outputFolder = config.files.incomingDocumentsDir + '/' + outputChildFolder;

    ++documentCounter;
    yield fs.mkdir(outputFolder)

    var xmlFileName = documentData.code + "-" + creationDateLongString + ".xml";
    var pdfFileName = documentData.code + "-" + creationDateLongString + ".pdf";

    const pages = [];

    for(var index=0;index < documentData.pages.length; ++index) {
        const page = documentData.pages[index];
        var data = new Buffer(page, "base64");
        var dataEncoding = imageType(data).mime === "image/png" ? "png" : "jpg";
        var fileName = "page" + index + "." + dataEncoding;
        var targetFilePath = outputFolder + "/" + fileName
        yield fs.writeFile(targetFilePath,data);
        pages.push(fileName);
    }
...
}
```

What I don't understand is why in the above code `page` only gets assigned once, on the first iteration, and holds that same value during the other iterations. So if I have 5 pages I end up 5 times with the data of the first page in that variable.

I am running node 4 without any special arguments or postprocessor. Simply `npm run ...` which maps to a `node src/main/myApp.js` in my `package.json`

I am probably missing something simple here but I've never seen this before when doing client side ES6 code. The big difference of course being that the client side code goes through Babel + Webpack and the server side code is ran directly through node.

Small addendum: if you are wondering why the "old school" for syntax and not something along the lines of `pages.forEach(....`, it's because this is existing code where I just did a few minor modifications.

Comment: I'm not getting the same result. Show more of your code please. (also... `var` -> `let`)

Comment: I know about the var -> let stuff too. Hence my remark in the last paragraph. Wasn't going to refactor the entire file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work as you are expecting in strict mode. Try adding...

```
"use strict";
```

You will only see this behavior in environments (like Node) that actually respect and enforce the keyword. Babel simply converts all `let` and `const` to `var` right now to provide `ES5` compatibility. To demonstrate, take a look at this Babel [example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20hi%20%3D%20'hey'). You can see in the output that `const` has been changed to `var`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just wondering, why doesn't it throw an error when running that code when it encounters the declaration for a second time in the for loop?

Comment: So I was trying to find out and realized that it works in strict mode. I edited my answeer. I believe this isn't technically a redeclaration because const is block scoped like let. At some point, node was throwing when you attempted to use let and const outside of strict mode but it seems to be silent now and even behaving strangely like in this case

Comment: `const` is block-scoped, once the loop enters a new iteration it re-enters it's scope, thus you can re-declare it.

Comment: So the code works if I use strict mode, but it "bugs" without any warnings/errors if I omit strict mode? Strange, isn't it?